# I need help renting a room in Riverwood but the lady is killing me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The lady that owns the Riverwood Hotel has been killing me and she is part of my quest so I can't kill her. I need to talk to her but I can't because she is killing me. What should I do?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Check your powers and a give effects. You're not a vampire, by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

You might need to restore from an earlier Save - if Delphine is attacking you, it must be that you have already done something that upset her for instance you accidently hit her with a weapon, or attacked a resident of the village.

There might be a way of correcting the problem, by paying any bounty you have, but going back to an earlier save might be far easier.

Answer (score 3):

Try resting outside of town for a week.  This can reset some NPC oddities.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Whiterun and commit a crime. Then pay the bounty or give jail time. Return to Riverwood to find your needed NPC free of any hostile actions.